# How can I persist my custom preview component in React Dropzone Uploader?

Tags: reactjs

My `DropzoneUploader` component from the [react-dropzone-uploader npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-uploader) has a custom preview component that is optional for display purposes. When I navigate to another route in my app using `react-router-dom`, the component unmounts. When i navigate to the route with the component, the optional preview component no longer has the data. It's as if there is an on/off switch for the preview component; it turns on when an action is performed, and turned off when the component unmounts (obviously).

The Preview Component is only rendered when the submit button is pressed, or autoUpload is set to true when you drag and drop a file in the zone. The [docs](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/props) do not give a clear way to retain the custom preview component.

```
<Dropzone
    inputContent={<DragAndDropText key={uuid()}/>}
    getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
    classNames={classNames}
    maxFiles={1}
    accept=".dwg,.dxf"
    PreviewComponent={PreviewComponent}
    autoUpload={true}
    maxSizeBytes={21000000}
    onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
    initialFiles={file}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the initialFiles arg simply needed to be an array, not the actual file:

```
<Dropzone
    inputContent={<DragAndDropText key={uuid()}/>}
    getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
    classNames={classNames}
    maxFiles={1}
    accept=".dwg,.dxf"
    PreviewComponent={PreviewComponent}
    autoUpload={true}
    maxSizeBytes={21000000}
    onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
    initialFiles={file} // this is wrong
/>
```

`initialFiles={[file]}` is the correct format. using redux to store input files I can conditionally render by using `initialFiles={file ? [file] : null}`